# Cannot disable warning in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I need to disable all warnings from a directory of a project which uses the external library ProtocolBuffers, which produces its own warnings.

These are some of the 151 warnings I get:

```
my.pb.cc: warning C4512: 'google::protobuf::FatalException' : assignment operator could not be generated
my.pb.cc: warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from '__int64' to 'int', possible loss of data
my.pb.cc: warning C4125: decimal digit terminates octal escape sequence
my.pb.cc: warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
my.pb.cc
xutility(2132): warning C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.
```

Where `xutility` is a Visual Studio include file.

If I add these lines in my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
# Use a lower warning level threshold for autogenerated files
set(PROTOBUF_FILES_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/src/*.pb.*")
file(GLOB PROTOBUF_FILES ${PROTOBUF_FILES_PATH})
set_source_files_properties(${PROTOBUF_FILES} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS /W2)
```

I get all warnings from my generated `pb.cc` files disabled, but I still have 15 warnings left from ProtoBuf's internal code, of the type:

```
my.pb.cc
xutility(2132): warning C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.
```

How can I disable these last warnings, possibly adjusting my CMakeLists.txt file adding the `-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` option, just for files with extension `*.pb.*`, considering I cannot modify ProtoBuf itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing much about `xutility` or how it is used by Protobuf, I would suggest trying to expand your `set_source_files_properties()` call to include [`COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html):

```
set_source_files_properties(${PROTOBUF_FILES} PROPERTIES 
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
    COMPILE_FLAGS /W2
)
```

Comment: Here it is: `Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xutility`